# how do I drag an object in libgdx using box2d?

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I have added objects to a `box2d` world in `libgdx`.
I am wondering if it was possible to drag objects with the mouse? If so, how?

thanks!

Comment: call myBody.sestTransform(x, y, angle) on each rendering loop.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options here.  You can use a mouse joint or you can use a kinematic body and set it's position manually.  A good example of how to use a mouse joint check this out:

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-backend-android-livewallpaper/source/browse/gdx-backend-android-livewallpaper-example/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/box2d/Box2DTest.java?r=ba02aaf34a8ca07daa0c30493bab993067c652f9

If you want to use a kinematic body you would do this:

in render():

body.setTransform(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), angle);

And then you would say body.getPosition() for the rendering of your sprites.  Or if you are using the debug renderer that will draw your bodies, but just as shapes.