# Assertion failed: (d + h * k > 1.19209290e-7F), function InitVelocityConstraints file ... b2MouseJoint.cpp, line 125

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm using a `MouseJoint` to move bodies around in `libgdx`. It has been working fine with `dynamic` bodies, but with a certain `kinematic` body I get a weird error that makes the game crash. The error is:

```
Assertion failed: (d + h * k > 1.19209290e-7F), function InitVelocityConstraints, file /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2MouseJoint.cpp, line 125.
```

Unfortunately, the stack is not shown upon crashing so I can't provide that. The error seems to be connected to the `MouseJoint` creation, but I did go step-by-step in debug and the creation itself goes by smoothly (or so it seems at least). Has anyone had the same error and survive to share his/her wisdom?

The code that creates the `MouseJoint` (which, as stated above, goes by fine. The game crashes elsewhere, I have no idea where) is:

```
mTmpMouseJointDef.bodyA = mWorld.createBody(mTmpBodyDef); // Create dummy body
mTmpMouseJointDef.bodyB = b_body;
mTmpMouseJointDef.collideConnected = true;
mTmpMouseJointDef.target.set(pTargetVec.x, pTargetVec.y);
mTmpMouseJointDef.maxForce = 1000.0f * b_body.getMass();
mouseJoint = (MouseJoint)mWorld.createJoint(mTmpMouseJointDef);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't use a `MouseJoint` with a kinematic body as `bodyB`, that's what is causing the assert (see [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735460/an-odd-cryptic-error-from-libgdxs-version-of-box2d-involving-a-mousejoint) about the same problem).

About the part from the Box2D manual you quote, it just states that in general, a joint between two bodies that are either kinematic or static can be created, but have no effect. However, this is not true with a `MouseJoint`, as it requires the `bodyB` mass to be non-zero (and in Box2D [all kinematic and static bodies have zero mass](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082973)).

We can see that by looking at the code in the `initVelocityConstraints` function (from the [JBox2D Github](https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/joints/MouseJoint.java)):

```
public void initVelocityConstraints(final SolverData data) {

    // some code...

    float mass = m_bodyB.getMass();

    // Frequency
    float omega = 2.0f * MathUtils.PI * m_frequencyHz;

    // Damping coefficient
    float d = 2.0f * mass * m_dampingRatio * omega;

    // Spring stiffness
    float k = mass * (omega * omega);

    // magic formulas
    // gamma has units of inverse mass.
    // beta has units of inverse time.
    float h = data.step.dt;
    assert (d + h * k > Settings.EPSILON);

    // some code...

}
```

If `mass` is zero, then both the damping coefficient `d` and the spring stiffness `k` are zero, and `d + h * k` is zero, causing the assert.

Comment: Upvote + accepted. Though I must say the `box2d` documentation on this is rather confusing.

Comment: @user2016436 I agree, it's confusing that this is clearly stated neither in the manual nor in the code comments. I think it may be because the MouseJoint was initially meant to be used only for demo purposes in the testbed.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the error is happening, but from [reading around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123470/how-do-i-drag-an-object-in-libgdx-using-box2d) I see that dragging a `kinematic` body should *not* be done via `MouseJoint` but rather with the `setTransform` method.

However, the `box2d` manual clearly [states](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974) (chapter 8.2) that joints *can* be used on `kinematic` bodies, though they do not affect them:

> ...Joints between static and/or kinematic bodies are allowed, but have
>   no effect and use some processing time...

So *why* I got the error is still unexplained.